# Recommended pattern to affect other Classes on instantiation/method calls

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

What is the recommended way to reference other classes within a container class while keeping everything decoupled?

In the below example, I'd like to automatically add to the `SceneGraph` the constructed `Path`.

```js
class SceneGraph {
  constructor() {
    this.children = []
  }

  addChild(child) {
    this.children.push(child)
  }
}

class Path {
  constructor(opts) {
    this.color = opts.color

    // @NOTE: Coupling here
    sceneGraph.addChild(this)
  }
}

// User space

const sceneGraph = new SceneGraph()
const path = new Path({ color: 'red' })
```

"Automatically" here meaning that I'd like to avoid doing something like this:

```
const path = new Path({ color: 'red' })
sceneGraph.addChild(path)
```

... which looks intuitive enough, but it soon starts getting clunky as more and more methods are added to the `Path` that should also affect the `SceneGraph` - i.e `path.remove()`.

The example above looks problematic to me, since the `SceneGraph` is inherently coupled with the `Path`.

Is there a pattern available that solves this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `PathFactory` which does nothing but create `Paths`.  `PathFactory` would be created with an instance of `SceneGraph`, so that `PathFactory` can "automatically" link the two without `SceneGraph` directly having a reference to `Path`.

```
class PathFactory {
  constructor(sceneGraph) {
    this.sceneGraph = sceneGraph;
  }

  createPath(options) {
    let path = new Path(options);
    this.sceneGraph.addChild(path);
    return path;
  }
}

const sceneGraph = new SceneGraph();
const pathFactory = new PathFactory(sceneGraph);

const path = pathFactory.createPath({color: 'red' });
```

Granted, this is displacing the coupling between `SceneGraph` and `Path` with an intermediary `PathFactory`, however it obtains what you wish to achieve.  Automatic adding without a direct relationship between `SceneGraph` and `Path`.

Comment: I've thought of this; It breaks down when more `Path` methods are added that affect the `SceneGraph`, i.e `path.remove()`. Apologies - I've edited the question to include this while you were writing up the answer.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides To `SceneGraph`, `path` here is just a child.  There is no coupling if you have a `SceneGraph.removeChild` function.

Comment: I was thinking `path.remove()` would be more intuitive; I'm trying to avoid add/remove operations on the `SceneGraph` altogether. To be honest, I'm not yet sure if the API I want is a sensible approach to begin with.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Hmm, you've already got `addChild`.  It seems sensible even expected to have a `removeChild`.  If that's not what you want, then you may have to rethink a bit what it is you want to do.

Comment: What I want is to write less lines of code in the user space - in an OOP-y way, for lack of a better word. For example, `path.clone()`, `path.remove()` are operations that affect the `SceneGraph` but look more intuitive as methods on the `Path` itself.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides If the actual work is done in `SceneGraph`, then either `Path` directly calls `SceneGraph` or you add some sort of intermediary such as `PathFactory` in the way.  By nature they are tightly coupled, but that may not even be a bad thing.  I would just avoid depending on a global variable reference.

Answer (score 2):

The Path and SceneGraph are already coupled as you except each Path to be added to the SceneGraph upon instantiation.

But there is a clear hierarchy here. The SceneGraph holds a list of Path children. In these cases, I find it cleanest when the parent container is responsible for the creation of the children. Then:

```
class SceneGraph {
  constructor() {
    this.children = []
  }

  newChild(opts) {
    var child = new Path(opts)
    this.children.push(child)
    return child;
  }
}

class Path {
  constructor(opts) {
    this.color = opts.color
  }
}
```

There are substantial restrictions with this solution. There is now a hard dependency from SceneGraph to Path. It is not possible to inject alternative Path implementations. If more flexibility is needed, then a separate factory as suggested by [Neil's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/365512) might be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support the nice syntax of `path.remove()` etc., I think you'll have to have the path have a link to it's container, ScenePath.  This introduces a troublesome cyclic dependency.  Whether this is worth the convenient API is a good question.  (I'm much more tolerant of circular dependencies than most) 
 Example code:

```
class Path {
  constructor(sceneGraph, options) {
    this.variousStuff = options.variousStuff;
    this.sceneGraph = sceneGraph;  // introduces circular dependency
    sceneGraph.addChild(this);
  }

  remove() {  // note - I'd name this "delete", not "remove"
    this.sceneGraph.remove(this);
    this.cleanupAnythingThatNeedsCleanup();
  }

  clone() {    // and might name this "deepClone" if that fits better
     let cloned = this.clone();  // or deepClone()
     this.sceneGraph.addChild(cloned);
  }
}
```